# Gradle reject snapshot if not explicitly requested

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am using gradle with dynamic versioning , i.e. something like this

```
dependencies {
    compile("myGroup:myModule:1.9.+")
}
```

I would like to reject any SNAPSHOT canidates, such that the above example would match `1.9.1` but would reject `1.9.2-SNAPSHOT`, except for the case that somebody **explicitly** required it.

So far, we worked with something like

```
resolutionStrategy.componentSelection {
    all { ComponentSelection selection ->
        if (selection.candidate.version.endsWith("-SNAPSHOT")){
            selection.reject("Rejecting changing version (SNAPSHOT)'")
        }
    }
}
```

This rejects all canididates ending in `SNAPSHOT`.
I learned that one can also access requested version using something like this

```
resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
    if (details.requested.version.endsWith("-SNAPSHOT")) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Is there a way to combine the two into something like this?

```
if (selection.candidate.version.endsWith("-SNAPSHOT") && !  details.requested.version.endsWith("-SNAPSHOT")) {
    selection.reject("Rejecting changing version (SNAPSHOT)'")
}
```